# Mongodb multiple aggregation match and group

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am fetching for category and subcategory i am using the following pipeline
`Category:`

```
{
                "$match": {
                    "category": {
                         "$in": ["list of my categories"]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "category": "$category",
                    "count": {
                        "$sum": 1
                    }
                }
            },
```

This gives me:

```
{category: category name,
count: totalcount}
```

`Subcategory pipeline`

```
            {
                "$match": {
                    "category": {
                        "$in": ["list of my categories"]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": { subCategory: "$subCategory", category: "$category" },
                    "count": {
                        "$sum": 1
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$group": {
                    "_id": "$_id.category",
                    "counts": {
                        "$push": {
                            "k": "$_id.subCategory",
                            "v": "$count"
                        },
                    },
                    "count":{
                        $sum: "$counts"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "$project": {
                    "counts": { "$arrayToObject": "$counts" },
                }
            },
```

This gives me

```
category: name {

subcategory1 : total count,
...
}
```

How do I join the two to get a single call to return something like

```
{category: categoryname,
count: totalcountforcategory,
subcategories: {
subcategory: totalcount,
subcategory2:totalcount}
```

**Update**

Here is my sample JSON

```
{
    "category": "Category one",
    "name": "Sample name",
    "subCategory": "subCategory one",
},
{
    "category": "Category one",
    "name": "Sample name",
    "subCategory": "subCategory two",
},
{
    "category": "Category two",
    "name": "Sample name",
    "subCategory": "subCategory one",
},
{
    "category": "Category one",
    "name": "Sample name",
    "subCategory": "subCategory two",
}
```

**Expected OutPut**

```
{
"Category one": 3,
subCategories: {
"subCategoryone": 2,
"subCategorytwo":3,
}
}

{
"Category two": 5,
subCategories: {
"subCategoryone": 2,
"subCategorytwo":3,
}
}
```

Comment: Show us your sample documents

Comment: updated with the sample

Comment: [Are you looking for this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TydQMu776u8)

Comment: i updated expected output

Comment: or i can say i want the count for all categories and for each category get count for all subcategories

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        cat: "$category",
        sub: "$subCategory"
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      },
      "subCategory": {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.cat",
      "counts": {
        "$push": {
          "k": "$_id.sub",
          "v": "$count"
        },
        
      },
      "count": {
        $sum: "$counts"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "counts": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$counts"
      },
      
    }
  },
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/udCzD88p3cf)

Comment: i did that previously but here is the way  i achieved it below

Answer (score 0):

I used `$facet` to join pipelines i don't know if it is best practice or not

```
const pipeline = [
        {
            "$facet": {
                "GroupAll":
                    [{ $project: { name: 1, category: 1,subCategory:1,votes:1 } }]
                ,
                "GroupTotal": [
                    {
                        "$match": {
                            "nominationYear": {
                                "$eq": "2022"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $count: "total"
                    }
                ],
                "GroupCategories": [
                    {
                        "$match": {
                            "category": {
                                "$in": ["Categories"]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$group": {
                            "_id": { category: "$category" },
                            "count": {
                                "$sum": 1
                            }
                        }
                    },
                ],
                "GroupSubCategories": [
                    {
                        "$match": {
                            "category": {
                                "$in": ["Categories"]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "$group": {
                            "_id": { subCategory: "$subCategory", category: "$category" },
                            "count": {
                                "$sum": 1
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    {
                        "$group": {
                            "_id": "$_id.category",
                            "counts": {
                                "$push": {
                                    "k": "$_id.subCategory",
                                    "v": "$count"
                                },
                            },
                            "count": {
                                $sum: "$counts"
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    {
                        "$project": {
                            "counts": { "$arrayToObject": "$counts" },
                        }
                    },
                ]
            }
        }

    ]
```

And here is my output

```
    {
  "nominations": [
    {
      "GroupAll": [""],
      "GroupTotal": [""],
      "GroupCategories": [""],
      "GroupSubCategories":[""]
    }
  ],
  "total": ""
}
```

I achieved it using `$facet` to join multiple pipelines